# Installing OS from a flash drive's directory?

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I have quite huge (64GB) flash drive with some data on it. And I'm wondering if it's possible to create a directory with bootable Windows 7 / 8 / Linux on that pendrive so I'd be able to install OS using this pendrive WITHOUT losing any other data?

Because right now it seems like you have to totally wipe out your pendrive then make it bootable using Rufus or some other app.

Is it even possible to achieve what I want to do? :)

I came up with one simple idea - create a bootable OS disk first then create a new directory on it called "Files" or something like this and store my files within it - should work but will create chaos (like xx files in top pendrive directory and then everything else deeper in my folder). And what if I want to have more than 1 bootable OS there? (I want just one in fact, just wondering ;))

Any hints?

Comment: Just place the bootable .iso on the flash drive.  There are several hundred tools that can do that

Comment: Yes, but most of them require me to wipe out the flash drive before.

Comment: You have to make the disk bootable before you can do that.  Backup the data, do that, then place the data back on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

as food for thought Ramhound is correct,  but also consider that IF Your USB stick is Identified by Windows as a Fixed Hard Drive and Not Removable, you can then Create 2 Partitions, if it's REMOVABLE then you can only have 1